# Is there an intuitive explaination of the matrix $A^T A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an intuitive explaination of the matrix $A^T A$? I have seen this in many field and it is also a matrix with a lot of good properties. Is there some intuitive explaination of it or a name for it?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2048577/81360) is relevant

Answer (score 6):

These matrices are sometimes referred to as [Gram matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).

One way to think about it is to note that the $i,j$ entry of $A^TA$ is the dot-product of columns $i$ and $j$ from $A$.

Most of the "nice properties" come out of the fact that $A^TA$ is always positive semidefinite (and symmetric).  Conversely, every (symmetric) positive semidefinite matrix is a Gram matrix.

Comment: I assume here that $A$ has real entries.

Comment: "Every positive semidefinite matrix is a Gram matrix" holds if you are defining positive semidefinitness over $\mathbb C^n$. If you define it over $\mathbb R^n$, it is not true.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Fixed it, thank you