# Geometric interpretation of $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, svd, geometric-interpretation

For a transformation $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ what exactly is the geometric interpretation of the transformation $A^TA$. If I understand it correctly the entries of $A^TA$ are the inner products or the columns of $A$ but how exactly should I interpret this geometrically as a linear transformation? And why is $A^TA$ often loosely called squaring the matrix, how does having the pairwise inner products (which normally are interpreted as projecting one vector on the other) yield us something close to a matrix squared?

One thing I've noticed is that using the SVD for a real matrix $A$ we get $A = UDV^T \leftrightarrow A^TA=VD^TU^TUDV^T=VD^TDV^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, but how does changing basis to $V$ and scaling by the eigenvalues squared relate to the concept above?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2048577/81360)

Comment: One consequence of your observations regarding the singular value decomposition is that the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ (which are also its singular values) are the squares of the *singular values* of $A$.

Comment: The polar decomposition is a really nice way to understand svd, thanks for that! This means $A^TA$ is the same as applying $P^2$ and ignoring $U$ which would map the vectors to a different dimension, this also maps perfectly with $VD^TDV^T$. One last thing I'm still confused about is the first part of my question, what does all of this have to do with the inner products of our basis vectors?

Comment: By $A = U D V^T$, I think you are referring to the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) of $A$. You may edit your question and add this info - along with the detail that $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices.

Comment: An intuitive way to understand this matrix $A^T A$ is as representing the pullback of the Euclidean scalar product by $A$. This scalar product is $\langle A x, A y \rangle$. SVD expresses the matrix $A$ as a diagonal matrix by choosing correctly the orthonormal basis of the source and target, and your observation is intuitively explained by this coordinate-free point of view.

Comment: What I mean is that this matrix should probably be thought of as representing a bilinear form and not a linear transformation.

Comment: If I recall correctly, SVD is more or less the same thing as ortho-diagonalizing this bilinear form $A^T A$, right?

Comment: can you give me a link or explain in a short form what pullback means in the context of the scalar product, I'm sorry but I've never really deeply studied mathematics, just some intro courses for my CS degree.

Comment: Do you know what is a bilinear form? If you have a linear map $f : V→W$ between two vector spaces and if $b(-,-)$ is a bilinear form on $W$, you can "pull it back to $V$" via $f$, and it gives $(x,y) ∈ V^2 ↦ b(f(x),f(y))$. Do you think this is something intuitive to do? For instance, if you look at the unit sphere in $W$, the unit sphere of the pullback of the scalar product will be an ellipsoid in $V$ (and the "principal axis" of this ellipsoid gives you the SVD of $f$).

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are two Euclidean spaces, and if $f$ is injective, this "pullback" of the scalar product of $W$ will again be a scalar product on $V$ (do you see why?). This way, we see for instance that if $f$ is represented by the matrix $A$, then $f$ is injective if and only if $A^T A$ is non-degenerate, ie has a non-zero determinant. Visually, non-injectivity corresponds to the ellipsoid being "degenerate" and "very very long" in one direction (so that it's a cylinder instead).

Comment: Okay so the pullback essencially encodes how to get from $f(x), f(y) = Ax, Ay$ back to $x,y$? And with this comment "What I mean is that this matrix should probably be thought of as representing a bilinear form and not a linear transformation" did you mean roughly what I commented under the accepted answer, that it's more reasonable to look at $A^TA$ as encoding information about the transformation instead of looking at it as a transformation itself? Please correct me if anything I'm saying is wrong, I'm definitly not in my domain of expertise ^^

Comment: I don't really understand what would mean by "to get from $f(x),f(y) = Ax,Ay$ back to $x,y$"... But yes, I mean that $A^T A$ should not be thought of as encoding a linear transformation. It should be thought of as encoding an object called a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form).

Comment: Yea I gotta be honest I don't understand what I meant by that as well, but I think I'm starting to grasp the general concept of $A^TA$ or $AA^T$ and why its used and also how this makes sense in relation to SVD thanks to the different view points in this thread, thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A^TA$ is a square matrix. As you said, its entries are the inner products of the columns of A.

The determinant of $A^TA$ will therefore be the Grammian of columns of $A$ and will be $>=0$ always. It is zero only when the columns of A are linearly dependent. To get an intuitive idea, you may think of the Grammian as the square of the volume of the parallelepiped (in $R^n$) formed by the vectors that form the columns of $A$.

If the vectors are linearly dependent, then of course all of the vectors can be written as a linear combination of each other and thus this volume is zero (It is easy to imagine this in $R^3$).

If they are orthogonal, then they are also linearly independent, and this volume is simply the product of the norms of the vectors, which agrees with the fact that $Gram(v_1, v_2, . ., v_k) \leq ||v_1||^2 . . ||v_k||^2$ where the equality holds under two conditions:

1. If $v_1, v_2,. ., v_k$ are linearly dependent (which is trivial), or
2. $v_1,. . ,v_k$ are orthogonal, intuitive idea behind which I've provided.

Comment: I think the gram matrix is the exact keyword I needed, I'll report back as soon as I have an understanding for it, thanks! It's beautiful to see how things come up in different contexts in mathematics

Comment: Okay after reviewing this and also the comments above I conclude that $A^TA$ holds information about the transformation of $A$ about how much it stretches space squared, where the total amount can be found by taking the square root of the determinant. From what I now understand I think I will mainly look at $A^TA$ as gathers information about $A$, not as a real "transformation of space" itself. Correct me if I'm wrong and thanks for your help!

Comment: To be a bit more precise, $\det(A^TA)$ is the *square* of the volume of the parallelpiped spanned by the columns of $A$