# Geometric interpretation of Gram matrix as a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the geometric interpretation of a Gram matrix as a linear operator? If I apply a Gram matrix to a vector, what geometric quantity does the resulting vector represent?

A [very related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434561/geometric-interpretation-of-ata?rq=1) was answered with a geometric interpretation of what a Gram matrix $G$ says about its original, constituent matrix $A$ where $G=A^TA$, but that question does not have any information on what a Gram matrix represents as a linear operator applied to vectors.

The context of my question is in the formula for a projector matrix to a subspace spanned by the linearly independent columns of a matrix $A$, in which the inverse of the Gram matrix of $A$ shows up:
$$
P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T
$$
I understand that the vector quantity $\color{red}{A^T\vec v}$ in the application of $P$ to a vector:
$$
P\vec v=A\color{blue}{(A^TA)^{-1}}\color{red}{A^T\vec v}
$$
is a vector equal to the dot product of $\vec v$ with each of the columns of $A$, but I can't figure out how to interpret how $\color{blue}{(A^TA)^{-1}}$ then transforms the result of $\color{red}{A^T\vec v}$ (i.e., what that inverse Gram transformation represents).

Comment: One way to think of $G$ in this context is as a sort of "correction factor". The matrix $U = AG^{-1/2}$ has orthonormal columns (but the same column space as $A$), so $P = UU^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A$.